# When do I say "front-left" vs "left-front", or how do you differentiate between sides?

Tags: vocabulary, hyphenation

Suppose I have a box in front of me. I have labeled the front, rear, left and right sides of the box (overhead view). Each side has two handles, labeled A through H.

```
     A        B
 ------------------
 |l     rear     r|
H|e              i|C
 |f              g|
G|t              h|D
 |      front    t|
 ------------------
     F        E
```

How do I refer to each handle by its position with a short but precise phrase? Assuming that box is always in front of me like this -- e.g., the left side is always unambiguously on the left.

For example, handle G is on the left side, and of the two handles on the left side (H and G) it is the further front one. So is it the "left-front" handle, or the "front-left" handle?

Put another way, does "front-left" refer to position F or position G?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. In the case of a car you can say either *the nearside-front wheel* or the *front-nearside wheel*. In Britain that means the *front-left* or *left-front*. Either is acceptable.

Comment: The phrase 'furthest front handle' makes no sense when looking at your diagram. Maybe you should label the handles A,B,C,D, etc.

Comment: @WS2 - Your comment doesn't work. Firstly it is country dependent and secondly 'nearside' refers to nearness to the kerb or the edge of the road. There is no nearside on a box unless it has wheels and is travelling along the highway.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I've updated to clarify the question. The example singles out handle G, which is on the left side of the box and is closer to the front of the box than the other handle on the left side (H).

Comment: @WS2: In this case, there are not four wheels, there are 8. So "nearside-front" and "front-nearside" are ambiguous.

Comment: There are wheels? Even if there are, it makes no difference to the answer. Nearside is only relevant on a road vehicle.

Comment: Wheels, handles, whatever you like; there are eight identical *things* at eight different positions. In my hypothetical they can't be visibly differentiated -- I'm looking for the shortest phrase that precisely identifies each one by position.

Comment: I can think of no unambiguous way, beyond something like "the left-most handle on the front" or "the forward-most handle on the left side".

Comment: left-side-near(G), left-side-far (H), right-side-near(D), right-side-far(C), front-side-left(F), front-side-right(E), rear-side-right(B), rear-side-left(A)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Ignore that I said *nearside*. It makes no difference. My point is that whether you say *left front*, or *front-left* makes no difference.

Comment: Unambiguously you can print the diagram you have shown here, tell the person how to stand and then refer to handles A, B, C ...G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of no unambiguous way in English to refer to any single handle out of the eight you’ve indicated on your ASCII box without resorting to circumlocutions.

*Front-left* and *left-front* are both inherently ambiguous, and I am not aware of anyone distinguishing them in any meaningful way.

The simplest and least invasive rephrasing I can think of would be to include the name of the side (as a noun, not as part of a compound adjective) as well as the relative position of the handle in relation to its neighbour; for example, handle **F** would be the *left handle on the front (side)* and handle **G** would be the *front handle on the left(-hand side)*.

That is quite unambiguous, at least to me, and though it is a rephrasing and a circumlocution, I don’t think it’s an unduly disruptive one in most contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the phrase 'front-left' in that situation is completely ambiguous.

The reason is that a box does not have hands. An observer will have no option but to relate to their own point of view.

If I am standing at the back of the box and facing it, front-left means E.

If I stand at the front of the box and face it, front-left means F.

The same sort of problem occurs with 'front left'.

If the box is a bomb then do not use any of these labels to describe how to defuse it. The interpretation would be subjective and dangerous.

Comment: Good point. Suppose the sides are unambiguously marked as front, left, etc. You said "If I stand at the front of the box and face it, front-left means F." Would G then be "left-front"?

Comment: If you’re standing at the back of the box and facing it (and the sides aren’t unambiguously marked), surely front-left would be **B**? E would be rear-left.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - That's exactly why I say don't use this terminology if it is in the least important. We're disagreeing even though I say it's meaningless! I assumed that the front was marked as front. You can unambiguously call something 'the front'. You cannot unambiguously describe left and right. This is why Port and Starboard are used on boats - it removes all ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction you are looking for does not exist, however, if you include both terms within the same context, your readers may intuit your meaning. If you want to be completely sure no misunderstandings occur, fight the urge to put it so succinctly. Simply write it out:

> The right handle on the front side vs. the front handle on the left side.

or explain what you mean:

> The right handle on the front side (henceforth named the front-right), vs. the front handle on the left side (henceforth named the left-front).

Answer (score 0):

**right-rear** and **left-rear** are [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=right%20rear%2Crear%20right%2Cleft%20rear%2Crear%20left&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cright%20rear%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crear%20right%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20rear%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crear%20left%3B%2Cc0) than rear-right and rear-left.

[The same is true](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=right%20front%2Cfront%20right%2Cleft%20front%2Cfront%20left&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cright%20front%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfront%20right%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20front%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfront%20left%3B%2Cc0) with right-front and left-front.

P.S.  The other handles are unnecessary :)

Comment: So what does that mean in relation to the question? Which, if either, would be used to unambiguously refer to handle F, but not G (or to handle G, but not F)? Simply saying that the other handles are unnecessary is not answering the question, which is based on the (presumably real, in the asker’s actual context) premise that they **are** necessary.

Comment: Although this bears no relation to the question, I actually find this really interesting. I've always said "front right" and "front left" but apparently that's quite uncommon.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet:  The OP should rotate the box clockwise when he needs to refer to the handles on side panels, so that the left side becomes the rear panel and the right side becomes the front-panel. It's a two-step process.   We could prefix the rotated  one with an `R` `R(front-left)` to signify rotation-mode-addressing.

Answer (score 0):

```
     A        B
 ------------------
 |l     rear     r|
H|e              i|C
 |f              g|
G|t              h|D
 |      front    t|
 ------------------
     F        E
```

G = lower left

H = upper left

A = top left

B = top right

C = right upper etc.

People might not understand what you mean, though, without a legend or diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using clocking references. Sitting on the box facing forwards, it's the second one on the left. The standard reference frame for this is the object's body frame, which is what the OP has done in his sketch. You would normally label the handles in clocking order as well, so that would make "g" be "b".